# keyframing in blender 3.4

Tags: keyframes, select, auto-rig-pro

when inserting a keyframe, should I only select the rig-frame(s) for the body parts that moved/rotated? Or is it better to select the entire rig (after adjustments) and then insert the keyframe? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: that depends on your use case. This answer cannot be answered in general. That's a bit like: which car should i buy? a mustang or a Tesla?

Comment: When I insert a keyframe, I can select the rig-handles just for the body parts that moved/rotated. OR I can select ALL the rig-handles even if they did not move/rotate and then insert a keyframe... for ALL the rig-handles. When inserting a keyframe (at any point) should i keyframe only the items that are different now... or bulk select ALL items and then insert a keyframe?

Comment: I would only create keyframes for bones that you actually have moved/rotated because this is how the [NLA editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/index.html) works. You can stack actions and the upper actions overwrite the keyframes of the lower actions. For example, a *blink action* that affects only the eyes, a *wave hand* action that affects the arm and the hand, and a *walk cycle* that affects all bones of the body work well together. If you create keyframes for all bones for the *blink action* then the character will just blink but not wave and walk at all.